# Can I Dynamically add files to deployment project?

Tags: c#, deployment, xna

I have an XNA 3.1 program and would like to create an installer that includes all the content files.  I know I can create a ClickOnce installer but it does not package everything up in one file.  Is there a way on build of the deployment project that I can look at the project folder and dynamically add the files and directories to the MSI?  On the PreBuildEvent There is already an xcopy of the files I want from the game project folder to the deployment folder.  What I want is a way to add those into the deployment project.  Custom actions don't seem to fit since they are for install time, not build time.  Should I give up and go the Wix route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find this project on github.  https://github.com/dump247/VDProjectXml  It looks like a good start.  I'll look into this and Wix.